# Epic ignores result of first promise when second action with same type occurred simultaneously

Tags: redux

My epic:

```
const myEpic: Epic<any, any> = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(MY_ACTION_TYPE).switchMap(action => {
    console.log("begin get ");
    return Observable.fromPromise(api.get()).map(
      response => {
        console.log("end get ");
        return resultLoaded(action.param, response);
      }
    );
});
```

then in some time i produce two actions with same type MY_ACTION_TYPE but with different param. Result in console:

```
begin get
begin get
end get
```

Why second "end get" is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Changing switchMap to mergeMap solved the problem.

Documentation on switchMap:
Like mergeMap() but when the source observable emits cancel any previous subscriptions of the inner observable.